# How can I select * from a table where a UID doesn't exist with a certain value in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have `two` tables and what I'm trying to acheive is to grab a `PhotoEmbed` code from the `Photos` table so I can then use it to display a photo on the webpage - Each time the webpage is reloaded it will show a new picture. But I don't want to keep displaying the same picture?! I want to display a new picture each time...So I've set up the following tables but Have no idea how to run a query to actually grab the `SELECT PhotoEmbed FROM Photos WHERE **CURRENT UserID** FROM Seen WHERE Seen **IS NOT EQUAL TO 1**`

If the `Seen` is equal to `1` then run the query again and find a new `PhotoEmbed` code.  Would you do this with a query or just `select * from Photos and all from Seen` and then USE PHP to determine what embed code to use?

Below Is a demo of two database tables. On the left there is the `Photos Table` and on the right (starting at userID) there is the `Seen` table.

```
| PhotoID | PhotoEmbed|    |UserID    | PhotoID |Seen |

| 1       |Filename.jpg|   |2         | 1       |1    |
```

Comment: you can simple use WHERE Seen != '1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all photos which are not in the seen table like this:

```
SELECT PhotoID,etc from Photos where PhotoID NOT IN (select PhotoID from Seen where UserId = 1)
```

**Given** if you insert only viewed images in `Seen` table (`seen` column,which I guess is `bool` could be removed), if you insert a new image I don't suppose for each user you should populate the table with `seen` set to 0.

**If** by any chance the user saw all images consider making a random fetch:

```
SELECT * FROM PhotosORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Played around with this for a while! Got it to work pretty well :) By any chance would you know how some websites make sure CONTENT that the user is seen isn't showed again?

I always here things like "Algorithms are used" or something to with an algorithm? Or would they use similar practises to what I've done and then just use an SQL query like you created? I was thinking that with tens of thousands of users and "Seen" content that your query may take a while to execute???

Comment: You could implement a caching system and limiting the query to a number of ex 10 (photos that haven`t been seen yet), be careful thought to reset the cache (or update). EX:
SELECT PhotoID,etc from Photos where PhotoID NOT IN (select PhotoID from Seen where UserId = 1) LIMIT 10

Comment: If the `SELECT PhotoID,etc from Photos where PhotoID NOT IN (select PhotoID from Seen where UserId = 1)` fails, it gives me a mySQL error because it's found no `photoID` (Because the `userID` has seen all of those `PhotoID's`) . Is there a way running this query `SELECT * FROM PhotosORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;` if the other query doesn't find anything?

Comment: Dont worry I just did `if($stmt->rowcount() == 0){ SELECT * FROM PhotosORDER ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;`